# Error al pasar informacion a traves de argumentos

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo un programa que se basa en la generación de streams aleatorios y la impresión de ellos en un archivo ".txt" . Bien, probé el programa de forma que sin pasarle nada a través de argumentos me lo hiciera y resultó exitoso. El problema viene cuando lo cambio para pasarle esas variables a través de argumentos, ya que me da error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0`

El código es el siguiente:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

 /**
 *
 * @author a19alexnp
 */
public class Lenguaje {

public static String generarPalabras(int i) {
    String palabra = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        int numero = (int) (Math.random() * (126 - 32 + 1) + 32);
        palabra = palabra + Character.toString((char) numero);
    }
    return palabra;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        String ficheiro = args[1];
        ficheiro = ficheiro + ".txt";
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(ficheiro);

        int numeroPalabras = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int letras = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroPalabras; i++) {

            fw.write(generarPalabras(letras));
            fw.append("\n");

        }
        fw.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e = " + e);
    }

}
}
```

He buscado información acerca de este tipo de fallo al pasar valores a través de argumentos y he encontrado que lo mas probable es que no se los estuviera pasando bien.
Yo uso netbeans y lo que hago es irme a propiedades del proyecto, irme a Run y ahí escribir mis 3 argumentos separados por espacios.
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Los parámetros que recibe el método `main(String[] args)` se colocan desde la posición 0.

Ejemplo:

```
java Programa nombre-archivo // ejecución del programa

args = ["nombre-archivo"] // contenido del arreglo args

String ficheiro = args[0]; // nombre del fichero en posición 0
```

**Actualización**

Código para revisar los argumentos recibidos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
```

Comment: ya lo tengo desde el 0 solo que mas abajo que este, no se si influye la manera de colocarlos

Comment: Agregué un código para que lo agregues en la función main para imprimir los argumentos recibidos  para verificar si están correctos.

Comment: me sale vacio, no entiendo porque

Comment: Tendrías que investigar acerca de la configuración del IDE. De momento se asume que el problema no está en el código. Igual podrías compilar el programa a mano, en  el directorio donde está la clase ejecutar  `javac Lenguaje.java` luego ejecutarlo `java Lenguaje parametro1 parametro2 parametro3`

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es que para ejecutar un programa con argumentos, no puedes hacer el run de la propia clase, si no que te vas al proyecto y ahí ejecutas el programa. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.